# Validate array of strings in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, express-validator

I wanted to validate each value from the request which is array of strings. Something like

```
emails: [ 'johndoe@gmail.com', 'jandoe@gmail.com' ]
```

Here is my schema

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    index: true,
    required: true,
  },
  emails: [String],
});
```

In my validation I wanted to make sure that each email is not already exists in the database. I've tried the following

```
body("emails").custom((value, { req }) => {
  return User.findOne({
    emails: { $all: value },
    _id: { $ne: req.params.id },
  }).then((exists) => {
    if (exists) {
      return Promise.reject("Email already exists!");
    }
  });
});
```

But the problem is if I tried to post multiple emails in array the validation fails and the data will be inserted to db. How can I check if one of the emails already exists and reject the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the docs of [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/), it mentioned that:

> If the field holds an array, then the `$in` operator selects the documents whose field holds an array that contains at least one element that matches a value in the specified array...

So you can solve it by:

```
User.findOne({
  emails: { $in: value },
  _id: { $ne: req.params.id },
})...
```

Comment: Funny thing I tried that and didn't work earlier and now it's working all well. Thanks.